# What is the TUI (text-based user interface) equivalent of "yes"

Tags: command-line, bash-scripting

What is the TUI (text-based user interface)  equivalent of `yes` or `y` in CLI (command line interface)? I am writing a Bash script which has the line,

```
sudo apt install -y iptables-persistent
```

When installing `iptables-persistent`, there is a TUI screen which asks a question which I would like to automatically reply "yes" to.

Answer (score 0):

This should keep it persistent and avoid the annoying TUI on installation.

```
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections

sudo apt-get -y install iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent
```